# C# bowling array program

Tags: c#

So I am having problems with programming a bowling application in c# to calculate 5 different scores, storing them in an array and returning the average, highest and lowest scores, I am having problems with the code for storing the array and returning the scores. Here is what i have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  //Declarations
  const double MIN_SCORE = 0;
  const double MAX_SCORE = 300;
  const int SCORE_COUNT = 5;

  int[] scores = new int[SCORE_COUNT];  //stores all the scores
  int inputScore;                          //stores one score

  double total = 0;       //to total the scores for average
  double average;     //average the grades
  double highScore;   //highest score of the games
  double lowScore;    //lowest score of the games

  //INPUT

  //loop to get scores
  for  (int bowler = 0; bowler < scores.Length; bowler++)
  {
    try
    {
      //prompt for and get the input
      Console.Write("Please enter score for game " + (bowler + 1) + ":");
      inputScore = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
      //valid range?
      if (inputScore > MAX_SCORE || inputScore < MIN_SCORE)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Scores must be between " + MIN_SCORE + 
              " and " + MAX_SCORE + ". Please try again. ");
        bowler--;
      }
      else
      {
        scores[bowler] = inputScore;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception myEx)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(myEx.Message + " Please try again. ");
      bowler--;             
    }

    //PROCESS
    Array.Sort(scores); 

    //OUTPUT 
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nAverage Score for Bowler:{0}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `using` statement:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then you can use:

```
scores.Average();
scores.Max();
scores.Min();
```

Simple enough.

Comment: thank you that works, but now it is not looping properly through the 5 bowling scores and just outputting the average, highest and lowest directly after the first score is inputted, any ideas?

Comment: You need to take your WriteLine call out of the for loop.

Comment: ya that works, but now it's not returning the max and min properly do i need to sort it differently or something?

Comment: Delete the `Sort`. It's messing up your array before you finish filling it.

Comment: did that, the average works fine its just the min and max, the min returns the 1st value of the index and that max returns the last value inputted

Comment: Always? That must be something in the code that I haven't seen. Try stepping through this in a debugger, and if you can't figure it out, ask a new question or post the new code.

Comment: @KendallFrey You are a victim of a help vampire.

Comment: @L.B: Not as bad a case as I ran into yesterday. :/

Comment: I think I got it thanks a lot @KendallFrey you were a big help!